# Excel - print top and bottom rows on each page

Tags: microsoft-excel

With the integrated page layout and print titles only one set of rows can be selected to be repeated on each printed page (like the top rows, the option is called "rows to repeat at top) but there is no option for bottom rows to be made repeatable.

**Is there a way to print the 1st few rows and the last few rows on a large table on each page, just like a header/footer system ?**

Comment: You wish to print twice the last row on each page?

Comment: I think you need VBA to do this as you cannot reference cells in footers.

Comment: another option is to use a separate worksheet for the presentation layer (printing) and use a formula to dynamically filter the data to lay it out as you want for printing.  e.g. from table 1 include the first 10 rows, then [optionally] one or more spacer rows, then the last 10 rows. etc.

Comment: @harrymc no, just table rows as footer.

Comment: @Blind Spots I attempted something similar, did not work.